# convert the reference back to a strong one inside the closure, memory management, swift

Tags: memory-management, swift2, closures, weak-references, strong-references

I'm experimenting the retain cycle in closure like following

```
 class Sample {
        deinit {
            print("Destroying Sample")
        }

        func additionOf(a: Int, b:Int) {
            print("Addition is \(a + b)")
        }

        func closure() {                
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0)) { [weak self] in
            self?.additionOf(3, b: 3)   
            usleep(500)                 
            self?.additionOf(3, b: 5)  
          }
        }
    }
```

Later at some point, I'm doing

```
var sample : Sample? = Sample()
sample?.closure()

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0)) {
  usleep(100)
  sample = nil
}
```

The output will be

```
Addition is 6
Destroying Sample
```

This is understandable because `self` is nil out before doing `self?.additionOf(3, b:5)`

If I made a change inside the closure  by creating another variable which references to `[weak self]` like following

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0)) { [weak self] in
   guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
   strongSelf.additionOf(3, b: 3)
   usleep(500)
   strongSelf.additionOf(3, b: 5)
}
```

This time, the output is

```
Addition is 6
Addition is 8
Destroying C
```

My question is why `strongSelf` is not nil out after `sample = nil`. Is it because it is captured inside the closure before `sample = nil`

Comment: When you set `sample = nil`, all you're doing is resolving that one particular strong reference to the `Sample`. But it has no effect on any other strong references that might be out there (such as `strongSelf`, which was assigned before you did `sample = nil`). The entire purpose of doing a `strongSelf` pattern inside the `[weak self]` closure (sometimes jokingly called the "strongSelf/weakSelf dance") is to make sure that if that `Sample` wasn't deallocated when that closure started, it will keep it around until that closure completes.

Comment: @Rob: I think I understood but not 100%. From the OP, when closure starts, Sample has not been deallocated yet until the first `additionOf(3, b: 3)` is executed. I still not understand why `strongSelf` does not get changed  since self is nil out.Unless it is captured inside the closure ??

Comment: It's not that it is "captured" by the closure. Simply that the closure has established a new, second strong reference to the `Sample` object. So, when you called `var sample : Sample? = Sample()`, there was one strong reference. When the code encountered `guard let strongSelf = self else ...`, that established a second strong reference, for a total of two strong references. When you performed `sample = nil` on the main thread, there is still one strong reference remaining. Only when `strongSelf` falls out of scope is this final strong reference resolved and the object is deallocated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider the contemporary equivalent to your second example:

```swift
DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
    guard let self else { return }

    self.additionOf(3, b: 3)
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.0005)
    self.additionOf(3, b: 5)
}
```

This is a common pattern and it effectively says “if `self` has been deallocated, `return` immediately, otherwise establish a strong reference to `self`, and maintain this strong reference until the closure finishes.”

So, in your example, if `self` was not `nil` when this dispatched block started, so as soon as we hit the `guard` statement, we now have two strong references to this `Sample` object, both the original `sample` reference and this new reference inside this closure.

So, when your other thread removes its own strong reference, `sample`, to this `Sample` object (either by falling out of scope or by explicitly setting `sample` to `nil`), this closure’s strong reference is still present and will keep the object from being deallocated (or at least not until this dispatched block finishes).

In your comment above, you ask:

> I still not understand why `strongSelf` does not get changed since self is `nil` out...

Strong references never get set to `nil` just because some other strong reference (even if it was the original strong reference) was set to `nil`. That behavior of a reference getting set to `nil` only applies to `weak` references, not to strong references.

When your code performs `sample = nil` on the first thread, all that does is remove a strong reference. It does not delete the object or anything like that. It just removes its strong reference. And now that the dispatched block has its own strong reference, all that happens upon `sample = nil` is that the object that had two strong references now only has one strong reference left (the reference to it in the dispatched block). Only when this final strong reference is removed will the object be deallocated and `deinit` will be called.

---

FWIW, the `[weak self]` capture list actually does not have much utility if you are immediately dispatching to the global queue. You would probably excise it and just do:

```swift
DispatchQueue.global().async { [self] in
    additionOf(3, b: 3)
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.0005)
    additionOf(3, b: 5)
}
```

The `[weak self]` capture list is most useful if the closure is running at some later point in time, e.g., a completion handler or `asyncAfter`, where there is a practical chance that `self` might fall out of scope before the closure runs:

```swift
DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) { [weak self] in
    guard let self else { return }

    self.additionOf(3, b: 3)
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.0005)
    self.additionOf(3, b: 5)
}
```